# How to add values after get them

Tags: php, sql

I have fetched some values form database

```
$sql = "select today earning form sql where username =$username date= today"
```

The data in return will be dynamic as I don't know how many rows it will produce

I want to display a table of record to the user like the one below

date:today earning 100

date:today earning 200

date:today earning 11

date:today earning 1

Total earning today  312

So the actual question is as I don't know how many rows will be there how to count the total value of today earnings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one

```
SELECT SUM(today tearning) FROM `sql` WHERE username =$username date= now();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(today_earning) FROM sql WHERE username='username' date= now()
```